# Multiple Items in Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project-template

Using Visual Studio 2012, I have created a template file which generates a WIX project with a single product.wxs file with generic folder targets and components, etc.

I would like to expand this template to use include files, however my template fails to add the additional files.

The [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247115.aspx) has the following example code:

```
<TemplateContent>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.vb" SubType="Form">
        Form1.vb
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.Designer.vb">
        Form1.Designer.vb
    </ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.resx">
        Form1.resx
    </ProjectItem>
</TemplateContent>
```

I have the following code in my template, but only product.wxs is added to my project:

```
<TemplateContent>
<Project TargetFileName="Wix FIAS Template1.wixproj" File="Wix FIAS Template1.wixproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">Product.wxs</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">ControlPanel.wxi</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">Gui.wxi</ProjectItem>
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true">RequiredComponents.wxi</ProjectItem>
</Project>
</TemplateContent>
```

I would expect a new project to have the following files:

- Product.wxs
- ControlPanel.wxi
- Gui.wxi
- RequiredComponents.wxi

However, the only item I have is **product.wxs**

I have tried the  tags with and without the TargetFileName property set to the same name as the original file, but this did not make any difference.

**Edit**: Adding these files into a blank Wix project and exporting them to a template worked, however there did not appear to be any difference between my template files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further searching revealed [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx) on MSDN, regarding updating an existing template.

Specifically, once the files have been updated:

1. Start (as administrator) an instance of the Developer Command Prompt (on the start menu, under Visual Studio 2010 / Visual Studio Tools/Developer Command Prompt).
2. Run the following command: `devenv /installvstemplates`.

This reloaded the template and added all desired project files.